# Native runtime error with React Native app obfuscating code in release builds

Tags: android, react-native, proguard

I am attempting to create a release build of my React Native application. I am able to compile it and package it with the JS bundle. It works fine in debug mode. But, when I assemble in release mode, I get these [errors](http://pastebin.com/raw/YCC9VQ9j) thrown at runtime by JNI as soon as the first RN view is displayed.

I am using proguard rules very similar to [these](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/local-cli/generator-android/templates/src/app/proguard-rules.pro). They are in addition to the proguard rules already applied to my app. In addition, multiDexEnabled and minifyEnabled are both set to true. When I include `-dontobfuscate` in proguard, the app works fine, even in release mode. When it is commented out, I get the error above. Code obfuscation is a requirement for release. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** There is some discussion in this [Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5655), but there has been no discussion since February and a question regarding commenting out `-dontobfuscate` went unanswered. The long stack trace posted by @kristjanmik on Feb 3 is exactly the same error I am encountering.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be related to another 3rd party library: SoLoader.

The native library tries to access a static field in the Java class which has been obfuscated. To keep them try this configuration:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader {
   static <fields>;
}
```

More rules might be necessary, so if the above does not solve everything, I would also try:

```
-keep class com.facebook.soloader.** { *; }
```

Comment: This got me on the right track. It was still crashing even after adding the second rule. However, I could no longer see the logging in logcat anymore, for whatever reason. In the end, I got it working by generalizing the rule: `-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }`. I'm sure best practice would be not to make the rule so general, but I can't debug what else is crashing and don't fully understand the implications of generalizing the rule. Can you shine a light on either or both?

Comment: I don't have idea about `-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }` but it fixed my issue. thanks @MikeOrtiz